# Solutions of PDEs, and arbitrary functions - seeking elaboration and clarification.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that when solving ODEs, arbitrary constants can arise. However, in terms of the solution for PDEs, I'm not quite sure what is meant by the phrase 'arbitrary functions'.

I would appreciate it if someone could please clarify this phrase and give it more substantive meaning. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe an example will help clarify your problem. If $u = u(x,y)$, then, if $u_{y} = 0$ we have $u(x,y) = f(x)$ for an arbitrary function $f$. When we say arbitrary function, we mean _any_ function $f$ that is of only one variable (here, $x$). This is because $\partial_{y} f(x) = 0$ i.e when doing partial derivatives, we consider the variables that aren't being differentiated _constants_.

Comment: @Mattos I have an example here where the solution of $ \dfrac{ \partial u }{ \partial x} + \dfrac{ \partial u }{ \partial y} = 0$ is $u(x, y) = f(x - y)$. However, $u(x, y) = f(x - y)$ is a function of two variables. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You have two derivatives, one in each variable. My example has one derivative, only in $y$. Though I think I may have misunderstood your original question now, so you should probably put some more context in. The solution to your PDE is also for an arbitrary function $f$, but this time your two derivatives, which are of different variables, meant the solution has two arguments $x$ and $y$. The arbitrary $f$ in your example is the same as mine. For **any** $f \in C^{1}(D)$ where $D$ is your domain, $f(x-y)$ is the solution to your PDE example.

Comment: For the example you gave, the function $f$ is arbitrary since any $f$ you write down will solve the PDE (wave equation), so long as its argument is $x-y$.  For example, if you give me $f(v)  =v^2$ or $f(v) = \sin(v)$, then the functions $(x-y)^2$ and $\sin(x-y)$ will solve the wave equation.

Comment: Your responses have been illuminating. My thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider arbitrary constants as arising from general solutions of ODEs.  Although these general solutions solve the ODE, the constants become determined once boundary conditions are specified.  We may extend this logic to PDEs:

Consider the Laplace equation.

$$ -\Delta u = 0 \text{ in } U.$$

Then, there exists a function $G(x,y)$ called the "Green's function" so that any classical solution ($u \in C^2(\bar{U})$) can be written

$$ u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} f(y) \frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu}(x,y) dS(y),$$

for some continuous function $f$ (this can be found in any standard PDE textbook; it is not important to discuss these details here).  Note that $f$ is an *arbitrary function* since any function $f$ you plug in will result in a solution $u$ of the Laplace equation. This integral expression serves as the general solution of the Laplace equation.  However, just as an ODE is not well-posed (unique) until boundary conditions are imposed, we must supplement the Laplace equation by boundary conditions, say:

$$ -\Delta u = 0 \text{ in } U.$$
$$u = g \text{ on } \partial U.$$

Then, as expected, $u$ is now uniquely defined by:

$$ u(x) = -\int_{\partial U} g(y) \frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu}(x,y) dS(y).$$